# Some odd character to appear in ie10

Tags: internet-explorer

In a tabled form, in ie 10 it appear some character that is not in the code and not in the css. It's like a "ß" in  and some .
Here a link : http://lukesonestop.com/contact-us/
I don't see anything in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I edit the the label, the pesky character goes away. delete the `&nbsp;` before the title. I think your css causes the issue with IE10.

change this:

```
<div class="radioPair">
   <input name="Question6" type="radio" value="Smoker &amp; Grills" />&nbsp;Smoker &amp; Grills   
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="radioPair">
       <input name="Question6" type="radio" value="Smoker &amp; Grills" />Smoker &amp; Grills   
    </div>
```